# Case statement with multiple conditions

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to do a count of active participants based on a field called `program_code` grouped by the name of the manager. But I also want a count of something else in the same query where three conditions have to be met.

```
select manager_name, 
       sum (case program_code when 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as F, 
       sum (case program_code 
              when 'FS' then 1 
              else 0 
            end) 
  from table1 
 where status='AC' 
 group by manager_name
```

But I want a third count of all participants who have a `possible_ind='Y' AND date_attended is not null AND status_cd='P'`

I can't put that in a `case` statement with all those conditions.  Is there a way I can do it?  Would it need to be a sub-query in the `select` clause?  I have tried it with a sub-query in the `select` clause, but it doesn't group it by `manager_name`.

```
select manager_name, 
       sum (program_code when 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as F, 
       sum (case program_code 
              when 'FS' then 1 
              else 0 end), 
           (select count(*) 
              from table1 
             where possible_ind='Y' 
               and date_attended is not null 
               and status_cd='P') as NEW 
  from table1 
 where status='AC' 
 group by manager_name
```

Comment: Are `status` and `status_cd` two different columns?

Answer (score 0):

You can omit the expression in your case statement and make your "when" statements more detailed.

```
select manager_name, 
sum (program_code when 'F' then 1 else 0 end) as F, 
sum (case program_code 
    when 'FS' then 1 
    else 0 end), 
sum (case
    when possible_ind='Y' 
        and date_attended is not null 
        and status_cd='P' then 1 else 0 end) as NEW 
from table1 
where status='AC' 
group by manager_name
```

Refer to [Oracle's example](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/case_statement.htm#CJAFAGBH) for more information.

Comment: This won't work because in the where clause I have the status='AC', in that third case expression I need the status to be P.

Comment: I took your suggestions to add more detail to the case expression and removed the condition in the where clause.

select manager_name, sum(case program_code='F' and status_cd='AC' then 1 else 0 end) as F, sum (case program_code='FS' and status_cd='AC' then 1 else 0 end) as FS, sum (case possible_ind='Y' and date_attended is not null and status_cd='PN' then 1 else 0 end) as NEW from table 1 group by manager_name having sum(case when program_code='F' and status_cd='AC' then 1 else 0 end)>1

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware they were the same column. Glad you got it working.